# updating value in $scope in a sub state not working angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent state which shows the list of apartments, on clicking any apartment a sub state is loaded which shows all the images for it. But value of $scope is not passing to ng-repeat. What possible mistake i have made here.

app.js :

```
state('projects', {
    url: '/projects',
    templateUrl : 'resources/partials/projectsNew.html',
    controller : 'ProjectsController'
}).state('projects.project', {
    url: '/project/:param',
    templateUrl : 'resources/partials/projectImages.html',
    controller : 'ProjectController'
})
```

Controllers :

```
decorpotCtrls.controller('ProjectsController', [ '$scope', 'cart', 'projects', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, cart, projects, $rootScope) {
        projects.getAllProjects().success(function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                data[i].APARTMENT = data[i].APARTMENT.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
            }
            $scope.projects = data;
        });

    } ]);

decorpotCtrls.controller('ProjectController', [
    '$scope',
    'cart',
    'projects',
    '$stateParams',
    '$rootScope',
    function($scope, cart, projects, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
        var project = $stateParams.param;
        projects.getImagesByAppartment(project).success(function(data) {

            $scope.images = data;
            console.log($scope.images);
        });
    } ]);
```

html :

ProjectsNew.html :-

```
<div class="pastProjects" ui-view>
<div class="col-md-3 .col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 imgContainerOuter"
    ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:query">
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <a class="shrink"ui-sref="projects.project({param : '{{project.APARTMENT}}'})">
            <img src={{project.SMALL_PATH}}>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="textProjects">
        <h4>{{project.APARTMENT}}</h4>
        <span>Bangalore</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

projectImages.html :-

```
<div id="gallery">
  <a href="{{image.HD_PATH}}" ng-repeat="image in images | filter:query">
  <img src="{{image.SMALL_PATH}}" alt="Photo 1" /></a>
</div>
```

when i am navigating from parent state projects to project ng-repeat doesnt works. I put a console log in ProjectController for the value of images its being populated correctly.

Comment: Which one is not working? I mean `ng-repeat` of `projects` or `images`?

Comment: You defined 2 controllers - `ProjectsController` and `ProjectController`, but you're using same `ProjectsController` for both the parent state and sub-state, is that done on purpose ?

Comment: my bad.... recorrecting it. ng-repeat of images is not working @RahilWazir

Comment: Did you check if your `query` filter is filtering out all the images ? Try removing the filter once